# Is an explicit hash required to pass in options in form helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The [docs for `text_field`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field) show its use like so:

```
text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

But in the example there’s no explicit declaration of the hash:

```
text_field(:post, :title,  maxlength: 30, class: "title_input")
```

How does this work?

Is rails recognising that the developer could only have meant one thing (that everything beyond the second element must belong to the hash)? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of an options hash. It's a feature of the language. Ruby itself allows you to define methods with an options hash, and after the first two required arguments (`object_name`, `method`) it will read any additional parameters as part of the options hash, as long as you pass with the correct hash syntax (`key: value`).

The hash itself provides flexibility so you can add anything that an HTML field will accept: `id`, `class`, `data-` elements, etc.